# Does a Talend connector to Google Contacts exists?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, talend

I have a pretty simple question (for once :D) :

**Do you know if a [talend](/questions/tagged/talend)connector to [google-contacts](/questions/tagged/google-contacts) exists ?**

I can't find one into http://www.talendforge.org/components/, neither on the 4 first pages of Google itself.

As a fallback, do you think it would be possible to wrap a Talend component around [google-contacts](/questions/tagged/google-contacts) ... I guess yes, and so I would be surprised that no one had already developped it !

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a Google Contacts connector in Talend but there's a problem in the fact that to access the API you will need to auth via OAuth2. There's currently nothing standard in Talend to help with this (although it would be pretty useful) but Gabriele Baldassarre who semi regularly answers questions under the Talend tag has built a series of components to access Twitter data which has a similar OAuth requirement.

His [website](http://gabrielebaldassarre.com/talend/ttwitteroauth/) might be a useful reference to building this should you want to do so.

**Edit**

As of 5.4 Talend's RESTful components such as tRestClient now support OAuth2 so it is possible to provide OAuth2 tokens in your RESTful connection to help you connect to web services secure by OAuth2. There's not (as of yet) a Google Contacts connector available but you could replicate it now.

Comment: Thanks for this useful reply ! I did not even figure that this could be a problem considering number of existing components. Thanks for the link.

Comment: There's a couple of feature requests in Talend's Jira for the tRESTClient (and other web service connectors) component to support OAuth 2 so hopefully they'll implement this soon as it is becoming a standard way to authenticate to a web service.

Comment: tnx for linking me! PS my name is with just one "l". With one "l" is a male name, in italian :)